# What's the process for getting a closed question re-opened?

Tags: support, faq, closed-questions

Does one simply wait passively for those who closed it to come back and re-open it -- assuming they are notified of your edits and comments.

Or is there a way to actively pursue it's "unclosing?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a closed question is **edited by the asker within 5 days** of the closure, or if **someone casts a reopen vote** (which requires 3000 reputation points), then the question enters the **[reopen queue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen)**. Users with the close/reopen privilege can browse the queue and decide to vote to reopen or leave the question closed. So generally, if you're the asker and have edited your question to make it reopenable, or if you've cast a reopen vote, there is nothing left to do.

If you've edited someone else's question and don't have the reopen privilege, or if the question has already been edited once by the asker but not enough to make it reopenable, you need to find another way to bring attention to the question. Any edit bumps the question to the top of the front page, but this can be hit and miss. If you feel that you've made an edit that justifies reopening the question, make your case in chat — there is usually someone around who can cast that first reopen vote that will push the question into the reopen queue.

If people have left comments suggesting improvements and you've made them, you can @reply to the comments to catch their attention. Don't abuse this: only reply 
to a comment if that comment states a reason for a close vote and your edit makes that reason no longer applicable, and even then do this only if the question isn't entering the reopen queue already.

If you really really think your question deserves reopening but it isn't getting attention, as a last resort, you can flag a moderator's attention and explain your case. Moderators generally prefer to let the community decide though. One case where you should feel free to involve a moderator is if there has been a meta discussion and a consensus for reopening has emerged.

For more information, see the [Reopening FAQ on the main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question).

Comment: This is another argument in favour of people voting to close to leave a comment, so that it's easy for the asker to flag the closer's attention.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that, once you have gathered enough reputation, you can vote for a question to be re-opened.

You can discuss the closing in comments on the question, or possibly on the meta-site, if unclear as to the reasons behind it (or if you think you've addressed the concerns that led to the closing via an edit or other method).