# Why was this Infinity Stone question about Thanos closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

**EDIT: Duplicates are duplicates if and only if the QUESTIONS are the same.**

The below link is to close-as-duplicate policy and the most accepted answer.
[Why is the close-as-duplicate policy so aggressive, and should we change it?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6952/65457)

> Duplicates are duplicates if and only if the ***QUESTIONS*** are the
>   same. (This is how every other SE site does it, by the way.)
>   Otherwise, we're asking users to wade through a bunch of totally
>   irrelevant information to find the one tidbit that's useful to them.
>   *Preventing* that sort of exercise in frustration was the reason StackExchange was invented, folks.

**Outline of the two questions**

My question [How does Thanos know how to use the Infinity Stones? [duplicate]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225530/how-does-thanos-know-how-to-use-the-infinity-stones)
I asked specifically asked about the "Time Stone" because, after "Dr Strange" we are told by Mordo that it takes more than a photographic memory to use the stone and that it requires training and an affinity for it. With that said in my question, I asked about how Thanos used it because you need training and practice to use it.

The duplicate question is this: [How did Ronan use the power of the Infinity Stone once it was installed in his hammer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99778/how-did-ronan-use-the-power-of-the-infinity-stone-once-it-was-installed-in-his-h)

The answer in the linked question is a good answer and I don't deny that it does have information about ultimately having Thanos wield all six of them with the gauntlet. This is the answer:

[image]

**Tl;Dr**

**The issue**

Even though the answer to the question could possibly be used to answer my question, I would say that it could only be used to answer my question if I had asked it around the time that that question was asked.

Since that question and answer there have been [12 MCU movies released](https://www.dailydot.com/parsec/mcu-movies-order-marvel-cinematic-universe-timeline/) with varying degrees of detailed explanations of the "Time Stones". Not to mention that **I asked for in or out of universe answers** and there has been quite a lot more revealed about the how the "Time Stones" work by various directors or writers.

For example, [Jordan D. White linked by ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/marvel-reveals-secrets-infinity-stones/) released a very important thing about the "Time Stones"

[image]

> It seems there's a certain synergy between the Infinity Stones. Each
>   Infinity Stone is actually powered by an individual's mastery of
>   another.
>
> - The Soul Stone is powered by the user's mastery of Reality. It can preserve the soul to allow for life after death.
> - The Mind Stone is powered by the user's mastery of Soul. It can grant telepathy, or intelligence.
> - The Power Stone is powered by the user's mastery of Mind. It can make a person more physically powerful.
> - The Space Stone is powered by the user's mastery of Power. It can allow teleportation through space.
> - The Time Stone is powered by the user's mastery of Space. It can allow a person to travel through time.
> - The Reality Stone is powered by the user's mastery of Time. It can allow a person access to the Multiverse.
>
> The comics have long since established that Infinity Stones are drawn
>   to one another. An individual who possesses one Infinity Stone can
>   sense the presence of another. But it seems likely this "draw" will
>   follow the same pattern; that the bearer of the Time Stone will be
>   drawn to the Space Stone and to the Reality Stone, for example. In the
>   comics, that means the various bearers of the Infinity Stones will be
>   drawn into conflict with one another. **In the movies, however, it may
>   hint at just how powerful Thanos could become.**

There is also a [Reddit User](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/964ujl/every_time_thanos_used_the_infinity_stones/) who made a list of every time Thanos used an Infinity stone,

> [IW SPOILERS] I was seeing all these posts everywhere on how Thanos
>   used the stones in interesting ways. So I went through each and
>   everyone of the scenes in which Thanos is there and came up with the
>   following list. There are still something which I am not sure about,
>   so I have mentioned that as well. It's a list of every time we see him
>   use any of the stones.
>
> On the Asgardian Ship
>
> Power Stone - To torture Thor on the Asgardian Ship
>
> Space Stone - To stop Loki from Stabbing him
>
> Power Stone - To destroy the Asgardian Ship
>
> Space Stone - To leave the Asgardian Ship
>
> On Knowhere
>
> Reality Stone - To change the Reality within Knowhere
>
> Reality Stone - To convert Drax into Bricks
>
> Reality Stone - To convert Mantis into ribbons
>
> Reality Stone - To convert Star Lords blaster laser into bubbles
>
> Space Stone - To leave Knowhere
>
> In Thanos's Ship
>
> Space and Power Stone - To torture Nebula
>
> Space and Power Stone - to torture Nebula yet again
>
> On Vormir
>
> Space Stone - To get to Vormir
>
> Reality Stone - To change Gamora's dagger to bubbles so that she can't
>   kill herself
>
> On Titan
>
> Space Stone - to get to Titan
>
> Reality Stone - To make Titan look like the way it was before its
>   downfall
>
> Power Stone - To destroy the huge space ship part (or whatever it was)
>   which Iron Man crushed him with
>
> Reality Stone - To convert all the broken parts of that space ship
>   part into bats who chase after Iron Man
>
> Power Stone - To attack Star Lord with energy beams (we dont see
>   Thanos activating the stone, but we see pruple beams being fired
>   towards Star Lord impliing that it was the Power Stone)
>
> Space and Power Stones - To compress all the explosions caused by
>   Stark and to redirect them towards him
>
> Power Stone - To knock out Star Lord, Drax and Nebula
>
> Soul Stone - Once he has knocked out the three of them, we see the
>   Soul stone being activated, possibly to protect Nebula's Soul? idk,
>   wasnt clear
>
> Space and Power Stones - To pull the moon towards titan
>
> Power Stone - While fighting Dr Strange, to make an energy beam
>
> Power Stone - To destroy Dr Strange's mirror dimension attack
>
> Space Stone - To compress the debris from the previous usage into a
>   small beam tagetted towards Dr Strange
>
> Soul and Power Stones - When Dr Strange does the spell to duplicate
>   himself and restrain Thanos, Thanos uses the Soul Stone to figure out
>   which one is the real Dr Strange, and the Power Stone to undo the
>   spell and attack Strange
>
> Space and Reality Stones - To pull Dr Strange towards him while also
>   rotating the ground below, similar to what we have seen in the Dr
>   Strange movie
>
> Power Stone - To attack Iron Man with an energy beam
>
> Power Stone - To punch Stark
>
> Power Stone - To shield the Gauntlet from Stark's energy beam
>
> Power, Space, Reality and Soul Stones - He is about to do something to
>   Stark, before Dr Strange saves him so we never really get to see what
>   was about to happen, but he did activate all 4 of the stones which he
>   had.
>
> Space Stone - To leave Titan
>
> In Wakanda
>
> Space Stone - To get to Wakanda
>
> Space Stone - To make Bruce go right through Thanos and then
>   materialize in a rock
>
> Power Stone - To throw Captain America away
>
> Space Stone - To know out Falcon (we don't really see the space stone
>   light up in this scene, but it seems like Thanos's hands are made into
>   a fist, implying that he used a stone and before Falcon got knocked
>   down there was a surge of blue energy)
>
> Space Stone - To deflect the bullets which War Machine was shooting at
>   him and then to cripple him and throw him away
>
> Power Stone - To knock out Bucky
>
> Power Stone - To deflect Okoye's spear and to throw her away
>
> Reality Stone (edited) (or the Space Stone or both) - To knock black
>   widow down and cover her up with rocks from the ground (It could be a
>   combination of reality and space stone. There is a way we can know for
>   sure. When Thanos uses the Reality stone on Drax and Mantis earlier,
>   the affects are temporary. So if the rocks are back to their normal
>   position in the next movie, it could be the reality stone. Else, it
>   could be a combination of the reality and the space stone, or just the
>   space stone)
>
> Space Stone - To push through Wanda's attack
>
> Time Stone - To reverse visions death and the destruction of the Mind
>   Stone
>
> All 6 Stones - To attack thor with an energy beam
>
> All 6 Stones - SNAP!
>
> Space, Soul, Time and Reality Stones - To leave Wakanda and pull out
>   Storm Breaker from his chest, and possibly to heal the wound caused by
>   it. He uses the time stone to reverse the injuries caused by
>   Stormbreaker (I am not sure why he used Soul and the Reality stones. I
>   am trying to watch it again and again in slow motion, it seems that he
>   is using the 3 stones together for something, I am not entirely sure
>   whether that is the case, and if it is, then what he is using them
>   for)
>
> Hopefully I've got them all, but let me know if I've missed any.
>
> Power - 21 times
>
> Reality - 13 times
>
> Soul - 6 times
>
> Time - 4 times
>
> Mind - 2 times
>
> Total - 68 times

**Conclusion**
There is so much more information about how Thanos was able to use the stones now, than there was 4 and a half years ago and I only posted two links, I am sure there is more. Bottom line, in the context of things, the fact that 4 and a half years have passed and that the **duplicate question is "actually" asking** how Ronan was able to use the "Power Stone", I think that there is no way that it was a duplicate. The question should have been allowed to play out as it could have made for some interesting answers.

**Some food for thought**

I know some people are going to say that if I did the research for this and came up with this information now, why did I not do that earlier?

Ok, let's say I did that for every question I have had and every other user did the same and was able to get some good information about what they want to kanow and in the did not need to post a question. Then why have this site at all? If the information is elsewhere why not go elsewhere. When I ask a question here it increases content by two ways: 1. It creates a question that others may have thought about, 2. it then creates answers about the question and therefore increasing the content on this site. And increasing content increases people visiting the site.

So I won't apologize for asking a question and defending it when it will benefit the site.

EDIT: This from the comments, but I am adding it to this question. This issue with posting in the original question is that when people search the web for how Thanos used the stones, the question titled **"How did Ronan control the power stone"** will not come up. Posting a new question clarifies the title and therefore will make it easier to come up in a search, which means more views for the site. Not mention that none of this will answer the question **"How did Ronan control the power stone"** as it only applies to how Thanos uses the stones, **hence my insistence that this is a different question with different answers**.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question in a calm and reasonable way :-)

Comment: I don't really know anything about the MCU, so I'm probably not going to answer this, but my first thought is: if there's more information available since that old Q&A was posted, then wouldn't that be a reason to post a new answer to the old question, rather than posting a new question? Or does all that new info not really answer the old question?

Comment: @Randal'Thor, I thought about what you said the other day, it made sense. And I honestly do want to make the site a better place for both people who answer and create questions.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, This issue with posting in the original question is that when people search the web for how Thanos used the stones, the question titled "How did Ronan control the power stone" will not come up. Posting a new question clarifies the title and therefore will make it easier to come up in a search, which means more views for the site. Well , that is my way of thinking.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I didn't vote this closed as a dupe, but only because I didn't get to it first. And that's precisely the reason I would have closed it. There's lots of yummy info here, but all of it could be applied to the existing question *as an answer*.

Comment: @Valorum, If I posted this information it would not answer the question "How does Ronan use the Power Stone after he installs it to his hammer?".  This only answer how Thanos possibly could use the stones and therefore is a completely different topic. So no, I don't think I could post this as answer for that question. But please expand on how this information shows how Ronan uses the power stone?

Comment: Regarding your edit do we then need umpteen new questions for each character that used a Stone? No, of course not. We don't know how people use the Stones, the existing Q/A covers this already and could just as easily be applied to your question so they are dupes.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Agreed. "*Powerful beings seem to find it largely intuitive*" seems to pretty much cover it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, Really, you only need to generalize how anybody can use the stones. I was going to give you a heap of links to questions on "How can this character hold or affect Mjölnir", but why bother. In regards to your question, `do we then need umpteen new questions for each character that used a Stone` , why do you get to say no above and beyond the community. I am sure if we did not need thanos questions they would be down voted away to the depths of Stack Scifi, but it was not allowed to play out b/c you felt it should not. Why is that your decision and not the communities?

Comment: @KyloRen No because of the worthiness enchantment on Mjolnir there is something quite specific that can be applied to the individual for how they can lift the hammer. Now if you were asking "How could X use the Stones without disintegrating?" then that would be more comparable but still a lot more easily generalised than asking that of Mjolnir.

Comment: I like this question and most up-voted answer. `Duplicates are duplicates if and only if the QUESTIONS are the same. (This is how every other SE site does it, by the way.) Otherwise, we're asking users to wade through a bunch of totally irrelevant information to find the one tidbit that's useful to them. Preventing that sort of exercise in frustration was the reason StackExchange was invented, folks.` https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/why-is-the-close-as-duplicate-policy-so-aggressive-and-should-we-change-it/6958#6958

Comment: People who are saying this is a dup are basically going dead against what the most accepted answer in that question in my above states. `Duplicates are duplicates if and only if the QUESTIONS are the same.` They are not.

Comment: And why has no one explained why this is a duplicate in answer form?

Comment: @Randal'Thor,I am looking forward to a non biased decision from the mods on this site. I know I have done my fair share of stupid things, but this needs a non biased decision amongst the mods on this site as to if this is actually a duplicate. Also I think there needs to be a through explanation on what constitutes a duplicate as from what I have seen all evidence points to the fact that this is not a duplicate.People need to be informed. I ask for a detailed answer with the reasons why it is a duplicate and what constitutes a duplicate from a moderator.Single high rep users are not in control

Comment: FWIW the questions are the same because the both boil down to _"How does anyone know how to use the Infinity Stones?"_ and the existing answer on the dupe target already covers that.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, How do you know that each individual can use the stones in the same way? There are other examples of characters in many super universes using the same object differently due to their super power. So how do **YOU** emphatically know that every character uses the infinity stones the exact same way? Answer that.

Comment: Because we don't know how _any_ character can use the Stones. There is _no_ information on it. We have information on what users can do with the Stones but not _how_ they can do what they do or how people know how they can do what they do etc.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, I provided new information in this question. It shows a way how the Infinity stones can be used, but you did not allow that to happen. You were wrong, there is more information than what the question was posted as a dup 4 years earlier. You were wrong. You can't explain it, b/c you don't know. You made a hasty decision based on what you knew at that time, but you are wrong, there is much more information on how the stones are used.

Comment: @KyloRen The _new_ information can be applied to the old question equally well. The age of a question does not affect whether it is a duplicate or not. It just means if there is new information then either answers need updating or new answers adding. Why not do that instead of fighting over your own question?

Comment: Different character, same question because of what we know. All the "new" information you've included here would answer the old question _fine_. However, I can see you're not going to take an answer that is "it should be closed" so I don't see the point in carrying this discussion on.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, So asking how a certain character uses the Speed Force is the same question? And Don't worry I can provide information as to how different charters use the speed force.And it is not a question of how, but the fact that there could possible different uses iof the stones that we don't know about. But you are assuming that everyone uses the stones the same. A wrong assumption

Comment: But this question isn't about the Speed Force...?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, I will repeat my edit in the last comment.  You are assuming that everyone uses the stones the same. A wrong assumption. How do you know that?

Comment: I'll throw that back to you, how do you know they use them differently?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, Ahh , that is why we ask questions, to get answers. How do you know that it can't be answered? It is all on you to prove that it can't, otherwise it should be allowed to open and explore what answers there are.

Comment: Right I'll leave it there, I've told you why I believe it is a dupe. You don't agree and I doubt we ever will. FWIW the reason I threw it back to you is because you said _"A wrong assumption"_ among various other things telling me I was wrong but have yet to actually prove my "assumption" is wrong. I'll happily change my mind if you can but until then I'll leave this here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, You keep going back on you words. HOW DO YOU KNOW THAT DIFFERENT CHARACTERS CAN'T USE THE STONES IN DIFFERENT WAYS? That my friend is one thing you need to prove before you close a question. A question is asked to get answers (Which mind you you may not know about yet). So what makes you the absolute authority on this topic, this makes you the one who needs to prove that the stones are not used in another way? Not me

Comment: @KyloRen I made a non-biased decision, but that meant ignoring a lot of what you said because it wasn't really relevant to the duplicate-or-not issue :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor, I also would like clarification on questions where ***" How can X character use Y Weapon/Force/Ability?"*** Is it considered a different question in this case?  I alluded to this with the speed Force, like the Infinity stones it is considered to be something of great power of those who use it. But, a character like Danny West uses the Speed force differently than other speed force users. What I am trying to say is that how a certain character uses the same object/force/ability can vary from character to character, so how can a question referencing two different ones be the same?

Comment: @KyloRen That's the kind of thing that would vary case by case. Sometimes it would be clear that Y Ability doesn't depend on who is using it, and sometimes the answers would be very different for different characters. I don't think it's possible to make a single ruling there; individual judgement must be used..

Comment: @Randal'Thor, But that is the issue at hand here, who decides that "Y ability" doesn't depend on who is using it? That is the issue I have have with the "Dup-Hammers". Questions need more time to play out before they are closed, but as it stands right now it is entirely up to a user who may just feel like closing a question without much thought to this. As what has happened in this case here.

Comment: @KyloRen As I said, it's a judgement call, and people do screw up judgement calls sometimes. I've [written about this before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9788/31394), how as a mod I try not to use unilateral close powers in edge cases and would encourage gold tag badgers to do the same.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, as you know I am eternally never able to post on main meta, too many disagreements with old members who want to stick what was in the old days of the site. They even removed the recalculation of my up-voted questions with overhaul of the question system. That said, how does this site deal with these issues?

Comment: @Randal'Thor , When I say theses issues I am talking about these questions that are boarder line duplicate.

Comment: While it may have been true at the time posted, the quoted statement *"Duplicates are duplicates if and only if the QUESTIONS are the same. (This is how every other SE site does it, by the way."* is definitely not true now. If Question 1 has Answer 1 which is also an answer to Question 2, Questions 1 and 2 are duplicates and Question 2 should be closed as such. This is true even if Question 1 was posted (potentially years) after Question 2. The text of the close banner used to give instructions accordingly, that edits should be made to explain why the other Q&A don't solve this Q.

Comment: @Nij, So like in the answer in that meta post, are we expected to go through all questions answers to see if a question is possibly a dup? That is in reality not possible. So , as it stanads it is limited to questions that are considered the same not possible answers that could answer said question.

Comment: Yes, you are expected to use the search function to find relevant questions and see whether they handle your issue. It's called "making an effort to learn for yourself". This is why many duplicates should be downvoted for lack of research, because just looking for keywords often finds several questions that already cover it.

Comment: @Nij, Not what it says here, `Duplicates are duplicates if and only if the QUESTIONS are the same. (This is how every other SE site does it, by the way.) Otherwise, we're asking users to wade through a bunch of totally irrelevant information to find the one tidbit that's useful to them. Preventing that sort of exercise in frustration was the reason StackExchange was invented, folks.` https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/why-is-the-close-as-duplicate-policy-so-aggressive-and-should-we-change-it/6952#6952

Comment: I mean, I did actually quote that sentence, I think I might be able to read and comprehend the words, seeing as I also referred to contemporary accuracy and modern accuracy, and discussed the current situation. But sure, repeat it and pretend that nothing I've said is relevant, and keep wonderingly why everybody is disagreeing with you.

Comment: @Nij, You said `is definitely not true now.` . Where does it say on this site (that the post I quoted is no longer relevant) of what you are saying?

Comment: Oh, you're a prescriptivist. Because the only way something can be true is when it's been posted on meta, and not because it's what actually happens?

Comment: @Nij, So how do you expect anyone, especially new users to know what is what if it is not either written down in the rules or on Meta? On one hand you suggest "making an effort to learn for yourself" by viewing past questions to see if any answers are relevant to you ,but then when it comes to information on rules of posting dismiss that having then written down either in the rules or meta is the best way to inform people and having users make an effort to study these rules by reading them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've given this discussion some time, and examined everything objectively (i.e. without paying attention to *who* wrote what). There have been some spurious arguments put forward, and also some arguments that nobody has mentioned yet.

- The fact that new information has appeared since the old Q&A does ***not*** mean your question isn't a duplicate. New information coming to light is a reason to **update the old thread** (e.g. editing the existing answer or posting a new one), not to create a new one.
- The new information you've mentioned in this meta question could either apply equally well to the old question as the new (how the stones work in general) or don't really answer either question (a list of when Thanos used the stones).
- The fact that your question increases searchability for the site, specifically for search terms involving Thanos, again does ***not*** mean it isn't a duplicate. In fact, the purpose of duplicates is precisely to **increase searchability for the same question with different search terms**.
- The fact that you've found new information since posting the question doesn't mean your question is poorly researched or unnecessary. Certainly it says nothing about the question being a duplicate or not, so that's a complete red herring.

However, nobody has really mentioned how different the questions are from each other, not just in which characters they're talking about, but which aspects of stone usage.

The old question asks how Ronan can use the Power Stone **without having physical contact with it**. The answer duly addresses this aspect, focusing on how other characters have used the stones without touching them, as well as some later-realised speculation about Thanos potentially getting all the stones in the then-future.

The new question asks how Thanos can use the Time Stone **when he only just acquired it**. This is a separate issue from being able to use it without touching it, and the old answer doesn't really address that. The only relevant part of the old answer to this question is "*We don't really know much at all about "how" the stones work*", but of course if that was posted as an answer on its own it would be deleted as Very Low Quality. And we do know at least *something* by now about how they work, as the various comments and links have shown.

There may well be some specific information on how Thanos learned about using the stones, which wouldn't really fit as an answer to the old question. Valorum's comments on your question contain some information which, when supported by links/quotes, could provide an answer (which would be Thanos-specific and again wouldn't apply to the old question). So, not only does the existing old answer not really resolve the new question, but the new question might be able to get an answer which wouldn't fit on the old question.

### TL;DR: it's not a duplicate, but not for the reasons you say.

Comment: I'm at a loss why you've mod-hammered the question open **twice** when your meta answer (claiming that it's not a dupe) is downvoted.

Comment: @Valorum If you're at a loss why, then maybe you should read the answer you're commenting on, in which I clearly explain why. Also, one user (you?) downvoting an answer doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: Two users have downvoted your answer. And two gold badge holders have shut the answer as a dupe. Why bother posting an answer if you're just going to ignore the results?

Comment: @Valorum I posted an answer to explain fully the reasoning behind my decision. Would you have preferred that I just acted without explaining myself, as you did?

Comment: I explained myself in a comment above; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/why-was-this-infinity-stone-question-about-thanos-closed-as-duplicate/12884?noredirect=1#comment45016_12870

Comment: @Valorum, Exactly, no explanation at all. Like I have maintained all along it is up to the "question closer" to prove why it is a dupe. Although I agree with some parts of Rand's answer(not all) it is still up to the question closer to provide information why it is closed and in this case in not warranted. Just b/c you have "Star-Hammer" capability does not make you right.

Comment: @Valorum, not to mention the very person who originally closed the question has now posted an answer with positive results. Why? If the original answer that person proclaimed was sufficient, why the need for a new answer? All I can see here is a whole lot of contradiction.

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct procedure, but I down-voted the answer of my question on the main site, not b/c of the content (I welcome new content and is my ultimate goal for the site), but b/c the person who answered the question was sitting on new and different information, but still "dup-hammered" it.

Comment: @KyloRen I wouldn't say it's "correct procedure" - downvotes should always be directed at the content, and not the person who posted it - but at the same time, I don't think it's punishable in the same way that serial downvoting would be. Your downvotes (and upvotes) are yours to cast.

Comment: @KyloRen I don’t want to get dragged into this again but read what Rand has written here: _”The fact that new information has appeared since the old Q&A does not mean your question isn't a duplicate. New information coming to light is a reason to update the old thread (e.g. editing the existing answer or posting a new one), not to create a new one.”_ among a couple of other things.

Comment: @KyloRen Pretty much what F1Krazy said: you shouldn't downvote an answer just because the answerer previously VTCed your question (maybe he changed his mind about its dupe status in the meantime? someone accepting a mistake instead of stubbornly refusing to answer is a *good* thing, surely), but the most I can do about that is tut and scold you, because technically you can vote however you like.

Comment: I tried to take the down vote back, back it is locked. Did not know that was implemented.

Comment: @Randal'Thor,  I just want to clarify something with you. You said ***"In fact, the purpose of duplicates is precisely to increase searchability for the same question with different search terms."*** Are all dup's closed? Or can they be marked a dup but still receive answers?

Comment: @KyloRen "Duplicate" means a question closed as duplicate. Dupes don't receive answers, because the idea is that the answers would fit just as well on the other thread. However, dupes aren't "penalised" so much as other closed questions, e.g. in terms of counting towards a question block.