# Who moderates the high end users?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was going through the [protected questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions?filter=all&sortcolumn=protecteddate&sortdirection=descending&page=1) and I see that the user [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) is doing a lot of the protecting which is disproportionate compared to anyone else.

The issue I have is that there seems to be no one moderating the high end users like this one.

Case in point, my question about [Why was this Infinity Stone question about Thanos closed as duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/why-was-this-infinity-stone-question-about-thanos-closed-as-duplicate) which ultimately seems to be a mistake on this high end user, which used his power to dupe hammer the question closed. If I had not posted a disagreeing opinion the question would have been gone and forgotten (which I think happens more than those who do not complain)

Is there a clear and concise standard that Stack SciFi runs by?
If so, what is it and how are these uses moderated?

The case with the user [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) is that he is inflicting a lot a influence that I think is detrimental to this site. So who or what is moderating this individuals actions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sounds more like a (new) rant about TLC rather than seeking constructive input. You know what the usual process is: peer review, Meta discussions, mod flags, 10k tools etc. There's not much more to be said here.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, the reference to the down-votes is ultimately linked to this close-knit forum that tends to protect its own.  Your answer does not address the issue that high end users have a free reign and is wrong many times over. But , the fact that you have to post a complaint to heard is ridiculous. Why are you not addressing these issues?

Comment: @KyloRen What issues? You still haven't mentioned any actual bad thing which happened, except one of your questions being closed mistakenly (it was reopened a month ago, get over it). Can't address issues if there are no issues to be addressed, or if nobody's willing to say what the issues are.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, that is the tip of the iceberg, if you are so naive to think my isolated question was a one off, I have to question your position as a moderator here. To clarify before I move forward and be a accused of being unreasonable , do you really think that questions like mine are an isolated indecent?

Comment: No, but again, we rely (to a large extent) on reports from users. You can't expect a small team of moderators, who are not subject matter experts in every topic, to check every single closed question to see if it needs reopening. *Most* closed questions really should have been closed. Those that shouldn't will often either get reopened naturally or get taken to meta. The very simple answer to "who moderates the high-rep users" is "other high-rep users, and moderators if necessary". As I already said in my answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, My point is that these users are frequently wrong and what are you doing about it?  Stating these users are moderated by  other high end users is useless, ass they all are prospecting each other and nothing is changed. The system is flawed.

Comment: @KyloRen OK, to address [this comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/who-moderates-the-high-end-users#comment45243_12909), what I'm doing about it is monitoring these issues as they arise (e.g. in meta posts) and stepping in to correct matters if necessary (e.g. by reopening questions). I'm not sure what else you expect me to do. And if all the high-rep users are protecting each other, then that includes you with your 23k. You have enough rep to vote to close/reopen/delete/undelete anything, and to create meta discussions.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, I will never close or use my rep to influence a question... ever.... But you are back stepping.  If there was a legitimate moderation of high end users by other high end users then I would not complain. But lest face it, the people who down-voted my meta question on Thanos were most likely high end users and the up voters most likely not. I could see that as the initial commentators were against it. It was only after time that it received positive votes.

Comment: @KyloRen It's certainly true that *sometimes*, *some* high-rep users may support each other blindly. Especially on issues like duplicate policy, where the community seems to have split into two tightly-knit factions. But the SE model is *supposed* to work by high-rep users monitoring each other, and to a certain extent that does work. As a moderator, I try to monitor disagreements between users, e.g. on things like site scope or question closure, and take action when necessary. Sometimes I'm also the one taking an issue to meta for community discussion.

Comment: Also, since this is turning into a lengthy discussion, let's [move it to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104201/discussion-on-question-by-kyloren-who-moderates-the-high-end-users).

Comment: Kylo, @TheLethalCarrot, I've moved your comments to the chatroom for this post.

Answer (score 11):

### **Users are moderated mostly by each other and ultimately by moderators.**

The fact that one user did a lot of protecting of questions is not, by itself, a problem. Many questions need protecting due to attracting too many low-quality answers. As one of the site's most active reviewers currently, TheLethalCarrot probably sees a lot of these low-quality answers, which puts him in a good position to know which questions need protecting. However, all of these actions can be undone if necessary:

- If you see a question which was protected and shouldn't have been, you can unprotect it.
- If that turns into a protect-unprotect war, or if there's a pattern of bad protections, you can raise a moderator flag and ask us to look into it.

The above is pretty much a scale model of how Stack Exchange works overall (although question protection is a very minor and less-important aspect of the SE model, not likely to cause much harm either if underused or if overused).

1. Stack Exchange is **moderated mostly by the users**. Thanks to reputation-based privileges, someone who's contributed enough content to the site gains the power to close, reopen, delete, undelete, protect, unprotect, etc. This is on a **strictly volunteer basis**, so a high-rep user who doesn't want to take part in these activities doesn't have to. The natural consequence is that **some users will do more moderation tasks than others**, by way of being highly active on the site or simply being more interested in this kind of work.
2. To some extent, the system assumes high-rep users are trustworthy (there's even a privilege level called [Trusted User](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)). To spot mistakes, the system also relies on **users monitoring each other**: if someone makes a mistake or acts in a wrong way, it's likely that someone else will notice (see the first bullet point above). Wrongly closed questions can be reopened, and so on. There are various pages which enable high-rep users to review each other's actions: the one you linked about question protections, [reviewing reviews](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) in each review queue, etc.
3. If things escalate beyond that stage, or if someone has gone completely rogue, then **users who notice the problem can escalate to moderators** (see the second bullet point above). Some situations can't be dealt with just by user-on-user discussion. If there's a rollback war in edits or a close-reopen or delete-undelete war, a moderator can lock the post pending a final decision. Some situations, such as a user becoming abusive or refusing to desist from destructive behaviour, require extreme action like suspensions.

### What is the actual problem here?

The above is general stuff about how the Stack Exchange model works, which resolves the general *"quis custodiet ipsos custodes?"* issue. But you seem to have some specific grievance here; you say:

> he/she is inflicting a lot a influence that I think is detrimental to this site.

What exactly do you think is detrimental? You haven't raised any actual problem here. You've mentioned a user who protects a lot of questions (but you haven't mentioned any cases of a wrongly protected question), and a user who made a mistake in closing a question (mistaken closures happen a fair bit, and usually don't call for further action beyond reopening that question). Is there a problem that needs to be dealt with?

I understand that you may not want to air detailed concerns publicly. If there's a real problem with a particular user's behaviour, feel free to raise a moderator flag, or ask me to open a private chatroom if you want to say more than fits in a mod flag.

Comment: `What exactly do you think is detrimental?` The fact that any of the questions that  are not contested are deemed what the high end use has voted them as. Why is there no moderation of this?

Comment: @KyloRen Are you referring to question protection now, or something else?

Comment: I am referring to the moderation of high end users.

Comment: @KyloRen Well, that's what I've addressed in some detail in the answer that you're commenting on.